# ¿Como enviar un arraylist por ksoap?

Tags: android, ksoap

Saludos tengo una duda al enviar un array list por medio de ksoap, hasta el momento he envido datos sencillos como numeros, texto pero ahora quiero enviar una tabla completa almacenada en sqlite.

El primer paso que hago es leer toda una tabla almacenada en sqlite por medio de esta funcion.

```
public ArrayList<String> GetAllValues(String aTable)
{
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    db = getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + aTable;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            list.add(cursor.getString(1));//latitud
            list.add(cursor.getString(2));//longitud
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
    {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Una vez que la temina de leer y la almacena en la variable "list" trato de enviarla a un webservice por medio de KSOAP2 para lo cual ocupo esta funcion. Mi pregunta es ¿como incorporo la varibale list para que se envien coorectamente todos los datos alamacenados en ella?

```
private class TareaWSInsercion1 extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://prueba1.com/";
    final String URL = "http://prueba1.com/ServicioPrueba.asmx";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "MtdCoordenadas";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://prueba1.com/MtdCoordenadas";

    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        boolean resul = true;


        try {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);



            //request.addProperty("NOMBRE", Nombre);



            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try {
                transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapPrimitive resultado_xml = null;
                resultado_xml = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                String res = resultado_xml.toString();
                if (res.equals("1")) {
                    resul = true;
                } else {

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                resul = false;
            }
            return resul;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return resul;
    }
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: Cual problema es que te da?

Comment: Me da un error de serializacion, hasta ahora converti el list en JSONArray y luego en string para mandarlo. Se que no es la manera mas correcta pero funciono.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El objeto List no es un tipo que KSOAP pueda enviar, KSOAP esta diseñada para enviar datos primitivos por lo que LIST no pertenece a ellos.
Por eso crearon la serializacion y deserialización para que puedas deserializar un objeto.